# Laravel's mass asignment in repository

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was using the mass assignment feature of the Laravel 4.1 framework, and the problem began to appear when I decided to make my controllers more flexible by adding Repositories. When using this pattern I don't quite understand how to implement standard Eloquent methods as `fill()` and `save()`

This is my repository code :

```
class EloquentUserRepository implements UserRepository
{
    public function paginate($perPage = 15, $order = 'ASC', $orderBy = 'id')
    {
        return User::orderBy($orderBy, $order)->paginate($perPage);
    }

    public function getInstance()
    {
        return new User;
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        return User::all();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return User::find($id);
    }

    public function fill(array $data)
    {

    }

    public function update(array $data)
    {}

    public function save()
    {}

    public function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create($data);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        if ($user)
        {
            return $user->delete();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Has anybody made something similar? Thank you.

Comment: I think `fillable` can only be used in model.

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I want to invoke the object's fill method that is available in my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not the role of a "repository" class. Look at the meaning of repository : "a place where things are stored and can be found". I think you have to find an other pattern.

You can use a kind of procedural methods :

```
UserSaver::fill($user, $arrayOfAttributes);
UserSaver::save($user);
```

Or build a class on top of your user class :

```
$abstractUser = new AbstractUser($user);
$abstractUser->fill($arrayOfAttributes);
$abstractUser->save();
```

And I'm sure other (maybe better) patterns exist.

I'm not a big fan of all of this patterns because I think that Eloquent is already a good abstraction layer (or maybe because my projects are too small). If I want to change the implementation of `all()` or `save()`, I override them in a specific model or in my class `BaseModel` which inherits all others. I also use events like `saving` and a lot of [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes). Then my model and controller layers are very loosely coupled.

Comment: scopes look like something that I seek, will try and come back :)

Comment: seems that there is really no way to implement this.